# Reversed columns ('A' column at the end of a Spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm asked to solve this kind of problem, but it's too hard for me.
[Click to see reversed columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXK7o.jpg)

Of course, I want the sheet to show columns from 'A'. Has anybody got any idea how to figure it out?

Comment: Go into Excel Option ([alt]+F, T) then Advanced. In the Display section (about a third of the way down in the right pane) there is a Default direction option. Change it to Left-to-right.

Comment: There is also an option further down, still under 'Display' but for the specific worksheet that needs to be unchecked, its called 'Show sheet right-to-left'

Comment: btw, you can record these actions with the macro recorder if you are having trouble finding the correct VBA syntax for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that Excel 2007 has a diferent approach to reverse the order of columns from other Excel versions, as mentioned in http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win004.htm

### Excel 2007:

1. Open Excel and create a new workbook
2. Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor
3. Ctrl+G to open the Immediate window and then type in the window

Application.DefaultSheetDirection = xlRTL

Press Enter.

4. Alt+Q to close the VBA editor
5. Create a new workbook to test it

**Note:** you can type `Application.DefaultSheetDirection = xlLTR` to reverse again.

### Excel 2013:

Go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Display (tab) -> Default direction -> Right-to-Left.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Excel 2007 and I can't find the aforesaid option.